# Skip new line while printing with ternary operator in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

To print a statement and to prevent going into the new line one could simply add a comma in the end:

```
print "text",
```

But how can I do the same using a ternary operator? This one causes invalid syntax:

```
print ("A", if True else "B", )
```

Comment: Have you tried `print "A" if True else "B",`?

Comment: Do you think this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100721/skip-new-line-while-printing-with-ternary-operator-in-python/39100859#answer-39100859 solves your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] to prevent going into the new line one could simply add a comma in the end

The solution is in your question already. One could simply add a comma in the end:

```
print "A" if True else "B",
```

---

However Python 3 has been out for closer to a **decade** now so I will shamelessly plug the new `print` function that has much saner syntax:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print('A' if True else 'B', end=' ')
```

Future imports/Python 3 solved your problem efficiently, and the strange statement syntax is just a bad memory from past. As a plus, you're now forward-compatible!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using just ugly hacks, we can define function called below as `special_print` which every print locates in the same line:

```
import sys


def special_print(value):
    sys.stdout.write(value)


special_print('ab')
special_print('cd')
```

Result:

```
abcd
```

You can even mix normal print with `special_print`:

```
print('whatever')
special_print('ab')
special_print('cd')
```

Result:

```
whatever
abcd
```

Of course you cannot use any expression as argument of `special_print`, but with displaying variable it just works.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't see the connection of this answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
print "A" if True else "B",
print "Hi"
```

**Output: A Hi**

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can look at it this as one statement:

```
"A" if True else "B"
```

Then your print statement becomes:

```
print "A" if True else "B",
```

That should print "A" without the newline character (or "B" if the condition is `False`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `or` operator as well, like this:

```
a = None
b = 12
print a or b,
print "is a number"
# prints: 12 is a number
```

Just note that the expression above is evaluated **lazily**, meaning that if `bool(a)` is `False`, `print` will return `b` even if that evaluates to False too since it wouldn't bother checking (**therefore** `a or b` **is not equal to** `b or a` **generally speaking**). In the above example for instance, if `b = ""` it would just print "is a number" ([example](https://repl.it/Cq2k/1)).

Comment: i would appreciate the comment that comes with the downvote

Comment: Your answer is not applicable to the question.  `a or b` is evaluates the same as `a if a else b`.  But the OP's wants `a if True else b`.  Presumably the `True` is standing in for an unstated Boolean expression.

Comment: Also, the OP's error is in the placement of the comma, not in the use of the ternary expression.  The OP wants `a if True else b,` but writes `a, if true else b,`.  The OP could very well mishandle your solution `print a or b,` as `print a, or b,` and still have the same problem as you did not explain his error.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski appreciate it. when does `print a if True else b` actually print `b`?

Comment: Never.  That's why I said "Presumably the `True` is standing in for an unstated Boolean expression."  It's clear that the OP simplified the code when composing the question (using `"text"`, `"A"`, `"B"`, and `True` rather than meaningful values).